# Error: Response Status: 400 at PayPal Rest SDK

Tags: node.js, paypal

I created a platform with the help of NodeJS with some PayPal Payments, it all worked fine until now and I don't know why it's throwing me this error. 1 hour Ago I did a payment now it won't let me. I haven't modified any code or something like that.]

Here's the error

> /Users/calinonaca/Desktop/PEDIGREE-NOTES copy/controllers/feed.js:863
>               throw error;
>               ^
>
> Error: Response Status : 400
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/calinonaca/Desktop/PEDIGREE-NOTES
>   copy/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

And here's my function

```
exports.postPayment = (req,res,next) => {
    const uploadedBy = req.body.noteOwner;
    const finalprice = req.body.finalprice;
    const notename = req.body.notename;
    const loggedInUser = req.session.user._id;
    const noteprice = req.body.noteprice;




    const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost/successPayment/"+finalprice+"/"+notename+"/"+uploadedBy+"/"+noteprice+"/"+loggedInUser,
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "Note",
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": finalprice,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": finalprice
            },
            "description": "Note you ordered"
        }]
    };



    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++)
        {
            if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url')
            {
                res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
            }
        }
        }
    });

}
```

It all worked fine until now and I don't know what is wrong, can you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help, i had the same problem and i had to dig almost all possible links and resources, what i found is that you have to map EXACTLY SAME OBJECT AS [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/)

```
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "30.11",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "30.00",
          "tax": "0.07",
          "shipping": "0.03",
          "handling_fee": "1.00",
          "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
          "insurance": "0.01"
        }
      },
      "description": "The payment transaction description.",
      "custom": "EBAY_EMS_90048630024435",
      "invoice_number": "48787589673",
      "payment_options": {
        "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
      },
      "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "hat",
            "description": "Brown hat.",
            "quantity": "5",
            "price": "3",
            "tax": "0.01",
            "sku": "1",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          {
            "name": "handbag",
            "description": "Black handbag.",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "15",
            "tax": "0.02",
            "sku": "product34",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
          "recipient_name": "Brian Robinson",
          "line1": "4th Floor",
          "line2": "Unit #34",
          "city": "San Jose",
          "country_code": "US",
          "postal_code": "95131",
          "phone": "011862212345678",
          "state": "CA"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
  }
```

Only after i copied and pasted this object i got a successful response with redirect urls. I hope this will help you. I will play around with object to see if there is anything to neglect.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out I parsed a price format more than 2 decimals after comma or dot that was the problem

Comment: Thank you too i had, I had to add details with shipping and subtotal as it has validation their backend. My answer was not  exactly solution, all problems are with create_payment_json, it must be correctly constructed.